# How to simultaneously group/apply two Spark DataFrames?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

/* My question is language-agnostic I think, but I'm using PySpark if it matters. */

### Situation

I currently have two Spark DataFrames:

One with per-minute data (1440 rows per person and day) of a person's heart rate per minute:

```
 | Person |       date |  time | heartrate |
 |--------+------------+-------+-----------|
 |      1 | 2018-01-01 | 00:00 |        70 |
 |      1 | 2018-01-01 | 00:01 |        72 |
 |    ... |        ... |   ... |       ... |
 |      4 | 2018-10-03 | 11:32 |       123 |
 |    ... |        ... |   ... |       ... |
```

And another DataFrame with daily data (1 row per person and day), of daily metadata, including the results of a clustering of *days*, i.e. which cluster day X of person Y fell into:

```
| Person |       date | cluster | max_heartrate  |
|--------+------------+---------+----------------|
|      1 | 2018-01-01 |       1 |            180 |
|      1 | 2018-01-02 |       4 |            166 |
|    ... |        ... |     ... |            ... |
|      4 | 2018-10-03 |       1 |            147 |
|    ... |        ... |     ... |            ... |
```

(Note that clustering is done separately per person, so cluster 1 for person 1 has nothing to do with person 2's cluster 1.)

### Goal

I now want to compute, say, the mean heart rate per cluster and per person, that is, each person gets different means. If I have three clusters, I am looking for this DF:

```
| Person | cluster | mean_heartrate |
|--------+---------+----------------|
| 1      | 1       | 123            |
| 1      | 2       | 89             |
| 1      | 3       | 81             |
| 2      | 1       | 80             |
| ...    | ...     | ...            |
```

How do I best do this? Conceptually, I want to group these *two* DataFrames per person and send two DF chunks into an apply function. In there (i.e. per person), I'd group and aggregate the daily DF per day, then join the daily DF's cluster IDs, then compute the per-cluster mean values.

But grouping/applying multiple DFs doesn't work, right?

### Ideas

I have two ideas and am not sure which, if any, make sense:

1. Join the daily DF to the per-minute DF *before grouping*, which would result in highly redundant data (i.e. the cluster ID replicated for each minute). In my "real" application, I will probably have per-person data too (e.g. height/weight), which would be a completely constant column then, i.e. even more memory wasted. Maybe that's the only/best/accepted way to do it?
2. Before applying, transform the DF into a DF that can hold complex structures, e.g. like

.

```
| Person | dataframe  | key              | column    | value |
|--------+------------+------------------+-----------+-------|
|      1 | heartrates | 2018-01-01 00:00 | heartrate |    70 |
|      1 | heartrates | 2018-01-01 00:01 | heartrate |    72 |
|    ... | ...        | ...              | ...       |   ... |
|      1 | clusters   | 2018-01-01       | cluster   |     1 |
|    ... | ...        | ...              | ...       |   ... |
```

or maybe even

```
| Person |   JSON |
|--------+--------|
|      1 | { ...} |
|      2 | { ...} |
| ...    | ...    |
```

What's the best practice here?

Comment: When you say "I now want to compute, say, the mean heart rate in cluster 1 for each person," do you mean you want to compute the mean heart rate in cluster 1 over all people?  It seems you already have the mean heart rate in cluster 1 for each person.  Also, is there a reason you need to mess with your first DataFrame at all to calculate what you want?  It seems that all the info you need is already in DataFrame 2.

Comment: I updated my question a bit to clarify. I mean the mean heart rate for each cluster for each person, i.e. I want different means for each person. In this toy example you're right, the information was contained in the second DF completely. I've changed the column from mean_heartrate to max_heartrate, since in the "real" application, the info is not contained in the second DF either, they are just some additional meta columns.

Answer (score 0):

> But grouping/applying multiple DFs doesn't work, right?

No, AFAIK this does not work not in pyspark nor pandas.

---

> 1. Join the daily DF to the per-minute DF before grouping...

This is the way to go in my opinion. You don't need to merge all redundant columns but only those requrired for your groupby-operation. There is no way to avoid redundancy for your groupby-columns as they will be needed for the groupby-operation.

In pandas, it is possible to provide an extra groupby-column as a pandas Series specifically but it requires to have the exact same shape as the to be grouped dataframe. However, in order create the groupby-column, you will need a merge anyway.

---

> 2. Before applying, transform the DF into a DF that can hold complex structures

Performance and memory wise, I would not go with this solution unless you have multiple required groupby operations which will benefit from more complex data structures. In fact, you will need to put in some effort to actually create the data structure in the first place.